# How to solve this with LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list contain CategoryId and StatusId. If their is a specific Status then I want to remove all the CategoryId from the list.

[image]

In this example I want to remove all the StatusId = 1 and remove that CategoryId from the list as well.
So, in this case Id 1, 3 and 4 will be removed.

```
Dim list As New List(Of CatlogViewModel)

' CatlogViewModel has the property of Id, CategoryId, StatusId
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get all the categories for that status:

```
Dim categories = New HashSet(Of Integer)( _
  list.Where(Function(x) x.StatusId = 1).Select(Function(x) x.CategoryId) _
)
```

Then get the items where the category is not one of those:

```
list = list.Where(Function(x) Not categories.Contains(x.CategoryId)).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query against the list. Removing item would entail looping thru the values of a query and delete the ones found. `LINQ` is for queries not modifying.

```
Dim query = list.Where(Function(o) o.StatusId = 1).ToList 

For Each q In query
 If list.Contains(q) Then list.Remove(q)
Next
```

Or:

```
Array.ForEach(Of CatlogViewModel)(list.ToArray, Sub(q) If q.StatusId = 1 Then list.Remove(q))
```

Comment: Yes, I know but I want to also remove all the CategoryId of That StatusId as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
list.RemoveAll(Function(c) c.StatusId.Equals(1))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx

With MoreLinq which I discovered today you can be even clearer
http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

```
Dim categories = list.Where(Function(x) x.StatusId = 1).Select(Function(x) x.CategoryId).HashSet()

list = list.Where(Function(x) Not categories.Contains(x.CategoryId)).ToList
```